# Proving that a given space is not complete

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces, complete-spaces

I have the space $X=\{u:[0,1]\to \mathbb{R}, u\in C^2, u(0)=u(1)=0\}$ with the norm: $$||u||=\left(\int_{0}^{1}(u')^2+\int_{0}^{1}u^2 \right)^{1/2}$$ and I'm asked to prove that it is **not complete**.

I have trying to find a sequence of Cauchy that is not convergent in X, and I have the following one:$$u_n(x)=\left\{ \begin{array}{lcc}
             x &   {\rm if} & x \in [0,\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{(n+1)}] \\
             \\ -x^2+x+\frac{(n-1)^2}{4(n+1)^2} &  {\rm if} & x\in [\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{(n+1)},\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{(n+1)}] \\
             \\ 1-x &  {\rm if}  & x \in [\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{(n+1)},1]
             \end{array}
   \right.$$
It converges to the function that is $x$ in $[0,1/2]$ and $1-x$ in $[1/2,1]$, which is not  $C^2$ and therefore does not belong to $X$. How can I prove that it is a Cauchy sequence?

Comment: The idea to construct a sequence convergent to that function is right, but the sequence that you have written is wrong. Note that is not derivable on $1/2-1/(n+1)$ for example.

Comment: You're right, but I think that I've just fixed it. The term in $[1/2-1/(n+1),1/2+1/(n+1)]$ must be $$\frac{-(n+1)}{2}x^2+\frac{n+1}{2}x-\frac{(n-1)^2}{2^3*(n+1)}$$. Do you agree?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are implicitly doing is to find a bigger space $Y$ containing $X$ (and the induced norm on $X$ is the norm that you are fixed) which is complete. Then $X$ is complete only if it is closed in $Y$.

By the way, you have find a function $u$ not belonging to your space $X$, and such that $u_n\to u$ in that norm. This means that $u_n$ is not convergent in $X$, otherwise there could exists another $v\in X$ such that $u_n\to v$, and this imply trivially $u=v$, which is a contradiction, since $u\notin X$.

Now you have to prove $u_n$ is Cauchy. This is easy because $u_n\to u$, and so for each $\epsilon >0$ there exists $N\in \mathbb N$ such that $||u_n-u||\leq \epsilon $ for each $n\geq N$. But then, if you take $n,m\geq N$, then

$$ ||u_n-u_m||\leq ||u_n-u||+||u_m-u||\leq 2\epsilon$$

Thus, we have proved that for any $\epsilon > 0$ there exists $N\in \mathbb N$ such that $||u_n-u_m||\leq \epsilon$ for any $n,m \geq N$. This is exactly the property of a sequence to be Cauchy.

Therefore, you have found a Cauchy sequence $\lbrace u_n\rbrace $ of $X$ which is not convergent. In other words, $X$ is not complete.

Comment: But can you consider the norm of $u_n-u$? without problem? I thought that since $u$ is not in $X$ I couldn't do it that way.